# Override a package method, when that method is internally imported within the package

Tags: python, package, overriding, python-import

If I import a package, let's say networkx.

How to override one method inside it so that it's the one called by every other function inside the package ?

**Example :**

```
import networkx as nx

def _draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,
                        nodelist=None,
                        node_size=300,
                        node_color='r',
                        node_shape='o',
                        alpha=1.0,
                        cmap=None,
                        vmin=None,
                        vmax=None,
                        ax=None,
                        linewidths=None,
                        label=None,
                        **kwds):
     print 'OK'

nx.draw_networkx_nodes = _draw_networkx_nodes

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('A','B')
nx.draw(G)
```

I want the method draw to call other methods that will call my overriden function

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Did you mean `import networkx as nx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of how methods are called in python. You're patching the `draw_networkx_nodes` in the `networkx` top module, but it doesn't originate from that top-module: The `networkx.draw` method is imported from `networkx.drawing.nx_pylab`. This `draw` method down there locally calls `draw_networkx` which locally (still down in that file) calls `draw_networkx_nodes`. This is why modifying the alias that was imported in `networkx/__init__.py` doesn't work: it's never called internally.

So in other: If you want to patch a method of a library, see which sub-module it's originating from and patch it there.

So in this case:

```
In [6]: nx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes = _draw_networkx_nodes

In [7]: nx.draw(G)
OK
```

Comment: Is your point that the OP overriding `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` was the wrong base function to override?

Comment: yupp, sorry i was still editing the answer. hope it's clearer now

Comment: So the moral is *"You have to patch not just the function itself, but also all internal import aliases to that function"*?

Comment: actually you _only_ have to patch it in the (sub-)module it's originating from... if this is in some sub-module and imported to the top (as is the case here), you should just patch it in the sub-module it originates from.

Comment: re-formulated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't want to copy paste the whole code in a file just to modify a function. I was looking for the right and clearer way to do it.